# Creating a dataframe from a dictionary without the key being the index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've got a basic dictionary that gives me a count of how many times data shows up. e.g. `Adam: 10, Beth: 3, ... , Zack: 1`

If I do `df = pd.DataFrame([dataDict]).T` then the keys from the dictionary become the index of the dataframe and I only have 1 true column of data. I've looked by I haven't found a way around this so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: More detail

The dictionary was formed from a count function of another dataframe e.g. `dataDict = df1.Name.value_counts().to_dict ()`

This is my expected output.

```
       | Name | Count
------ | -----|------
   0   | Adam |  10
------ | -----|------
   1   | Beth |   3
```

What I'm getting at the moment is this:

```
       | Count
  -----|------
  Adam |  10
  -----|------
  Beth |   3
```

Comment: Add expected input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `reset_index`

```
dataDict = dict(Adam=10, Beth=3, Zack=1)
df = pd.Series(dataDict).rename_axis('Name').reset_index(name='Count')
df
```

[image]

Comment: I was after a dataframe but I can change the series to that anyway. Thank you.